# Do we have a tag for the SharePoint 2013 REST API?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I'm not really sure what it is called... whatever is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx). It seems to be related to the Client Side Object Model...

We do already have a [rest](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rest) (179 questions) and [rest-api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rest-api) (2 questions). What is the appropriate tag(s) for questions about the REST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally feel that [rest-api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rest-api) is a great tag for this.

Maybe it is a good idea to think about merging the two tags above though? This tag combined with a statement about what SharePoint version is in question should be well enough to scope this type of question.

Comment: I'd say merging the two tags would be beneficial.